# Atmel Studio: redefine weak function

Tags: atmel, gcc

I want to write my own implementation of SERCOM3_Handler. I put its definition in my main.c, try to compile it and get "multiple definition of SERCOM3_Handler" error. Why is this happening? The prototype of this function in the library headers is with the weak attribute.

Comment: It seems that someone else has already defined that function without the weak attribute. Doesn't the linker tell where that conflicting definition is?

Comment: What uC are you using? SERCOM3_handler doesnt sound familiar to me. Are you sure that is the appropriate name for the ISR? What function of the uC are you trying to use? USART?

Comment: are you sure you haven't put the definition of the function in a header file somewhere (as opposed to a declaration)? An alternative possibility is that you are #including "main.c" somewhere? Finally as @Wouter hints at the SERCOM3_Handler is already defined somewhere else - perhaps in a library? Actually just read - "the prototype has weak attribute" - try changing your declaration in main.c to be 'strong'

Comment: I am using SAM D20 uC. In startup_samd20.c library file there is following line:
void SERCOM3_Handler ( void ) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Dummy_Handler")));

Comment: In agreement with what others have said, I've had this happen when FreeRTOS defined a handler that I didn't think it was using. Just grep (or some other recursive in-file search tool) your project folder: `grep -rin SERCOM3_Handler`